# javascript hoisting for global variable and function

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I was wondering about hoisting. I know if global function name same with global variable, function overwrite variable's name. Is it right?

here is my code.

```js
(function() {
  console.log('console.log#1 ' + globalString); // globalString function 

})();

var globalString = 'I\'m globalString variable';

(function() {
  console.log('console.log#2 ' + globalString); // string
})();

function globalString() {
  console.log('I\'m globalString function');
}
```

It's result show me like blow

```
console.log#1 function globalString ()
{
    console.log ( 'I\'m globalString function' );
}

console.log#2 I'm globalString variable
```

If function definition overwrite variable's console.log#2 print globalString function. 
I don't know how variable and function hoist. 
please help.

Comment: Functions are moved to the top, so by the moment `console.log#1` runs it's still a function. Then you overwrite it with a string value. Only declarations are hoisted, not the assignments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function declarations (like your `globalString()`) are hoisted. To the interpreter, your code looks something like this:

```js
var globalString = function globalString() {
  console.log('I\'m globalString function');
};

(function() {
  console.log('console.log#1 ' + globalString); // globalString function 
})();

globalString = 'I\'m globalString variable';

(function() {
  console.log('console.log#2 ' + globalString); // string
})();
```

Before the initial IIFE runs, `globalString` is the function. After the initial IIFE runs, but before the second IIFE runs, `globalString` is then reassigned to the string. Ordinary assignments aren't hoisted - only the variable name is.

Comment: Wouldn't it technically be `var globalString;`, `function globalString()...`, rest of code?

Comment: I'm not sure, because it's a function declaration, not a normal hoisted "var". Regardless, whichever it might look like won't have any effect on the resulting script

Comment: The results you describe are, of course, correct, but I believe the "interpreted" order of events would be: 1. declare globalString 2. declare func globalString (which overwrites previous undefined var) 3. first IIFE 4. assign string to globalString (overwriting function declaration) 4. second IIFE