# JavaScript variable before and after declaration?

Tags: javascript, function, hoisting

```
function a(){ 
   console.log(typeof b); // function
   function b() {
     var c = 52; 
     console.log(c);
   } 
   var b = 88;  
   console.log(typeof b); // number 
}
```

Could anyone answer, how javaScript compiles or handles this particular case ? I know javaScript gives preference to `function` declaration when it comes to `hoisting`. But how a same `identifier` `b` holds two different values under same block or in same lexical scoping?

Someone could say like, okay, I'm going to use `b` as a `function` before it's declaration and as `number` after assigning it a `number`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of hoisting in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246589/order-of-hoisting-in-javascript) and [javascript hoisting for global variable and function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255345) and [Function declarations precedence/overwriting variable declarations? Hoisting? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015380)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can understand as such there are two phase of code execution

1. `Creation phase`
2. `Execution phase`

***Creation phase:-*** During creation phase function is hoisted at top as it is, while the variable are hoisted but there is no value assigned to it ( or you can say it's value is undefined )

***Execution phase:-*** During execution context it assigns value to variable when it reaches line where assignment is happening

so in your code during `creation phase` function b is hoisted, compiler will read it like this

```
function a(){ 
   function b(){
     var c = 52; 
     console.log(c);
   } 
   console.log(typeof b); // function
   b = 88;  
   console.log(typeof b); // number 
}
```

so when you reach to the line

```
b = 88
```

it assign a new value to variable `b` which is of type `number`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, those aren't 2 different references.

Internally,
`function b(){/*Code Here*/}` is executed as `var b = function(){/*Code Here*/}`
Hence, the first `typeof(b)` returns *function*.

And when `var b = 88;` executes, this basically assigns 88 to the already existing reference of *b*.
Hence, the second `typeof(b)` returns *number*.

Runtime image for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the hoisting happens as follows:

1. declare `var b`, without initialization
2. declare `function b`, which overrides the var declaration
3. assign value `88` to variable `b`

So the function actually gets converted to the "logical equivalent" of:

```js
function a(){ 
   var b; // hoisted
   b = function b(){ // hoisted
     var c = 52; 
     console.log(c);
   } 
   console.log(typeof b); // function
   b = 88;  
   console.log(typeof b); // number 
}
```

Note: [Only declarations are hoisted, not initializations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#Only_declarations_are_hoisted)